# Rating system for 5000 players

Tags: software, rating, websites, uscf

we belong to a state in India with over 5000 active players. FIDE rating tournaments and FIDE rated players are here but we wish to start a new internal rating system like the USCF or ACF rating systems. Are there softwares or websites for this? Kindly advise

Answer (score 4):

It seems that [rankade](https://rankade.com), our ranking system for sports, games, and more, fits your needs.

It's free to use and it's designed to manage **rankings** (and **stats**, including matchup stats, and more) for small to large groups of players.

Rankade doesn't use **Elo**, but its algorithm (called *ree* algorithm), although more complex (here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison) between most known rating system, including *Elo*, *Glicko* and *TrueSkill*), is similar to Elo if you play 1-on-1 matches only.

On rankade (besides other sports and games) we host many chess groups, clubs, and associations.

Answer (score 3):

There are two alternative rating systems - [Glick/Glicko-2](http://glicko.net/glicko.html) and [EloRater](http://www.garnergaggle.org/papa/chess/ELORater/help/index.html).

I believe the author of EloRater is a member of this site - @JimGarner. You could try contacting him directly.